# What version number should I use for minimum in ActionCodeSettings.Builder.setAndroidPackageName()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

According to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/ActionCodeSettings.Builder#setAndroidPackageName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)

the `setAndroidPackageName()` has three arguments. The first is the package name; the second is a flag specifying whether the app should be downloaded if it is not already present, and the third specifies a minimum version.

It is not clear from the documentation whether this refers to the version code, or the version name. I would like to pass the current app version into this method. Should I use the version code or the version name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning) says:

versionCode:

> is a positive integer so that other apps can programmatically evaluate
>   it, for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship

versionName:

> has no purpose other than to be displayed to users

So version code should be pass in your case.